# Set child div which has attribute matching parent div attrobite via style sheet

Tags: css

I have this html code here:

```
<div default_name="RandomName1">
    <div name="RandomName1">RandomName1</div>
    <div name="RandomName2">RandomName2</div>
    <div name="RandomName3">RandomName3</div>
</div>
```

The property `default_name` on parent div changes from time to time. I would like to set the child div which has `name` matching `default_name` to `background-color:red`.

Like:

```
<style>
      div > div[name=default_name_of_parent] { background-color: red }
</style>
```

I have no control over what the name values are, users set it. Is this possible via style sheet?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure CSS.

Comment: You shouldn't make up your own attributes. Use `data-` attributes when you need custom ones, and apply the proper attributes to the proper elements. In other words, divs don't have name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, if you make a rule containing a selector for each possible “combination”, like so:

```
div[default_name=RandomName1] > div[name=RandomName1],
div[default_name=RandomName2] > div[name=RandomName2],
div[default_name=RandomName3] > div[name=RandomName3]
  { background-color: red }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wc5whfwa/

But j08691 is totally right with their comment – this should be avoided at all cost if possible, `data-` attributes would be the way to go.